# Running Cron jobs in parallel (PHP)

Tags: php, parallel-processing, cron, fork

In the past, I ran a bunch of scripts each as a separate cron job. Now I'd like to run a controller script with one cron job, then have that call the scripts separately (and in parallel, all at the same time), so I don't have to create a new cron job every time I add another script.

I looked up `pcntl_fork()` but we don't have that installed. Can `fsockopen()` do this as well?

A few questions:

1. I saw this example, http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254, that uses `fsockopen()`. Will this allow me to run PHP scripts in parallel? Note, the scripts don't interact, but I would still like to know if any of them exited prematurely with an error.
2. Secondly the scripts I'm running aren't externally accessible, they are internal only. The script was previously run like so: **php -f /path/to/my/script1.php**. It's not a web-accessible path. Would the example in #1 work with this, or only web-accessible paths?.

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Comment: Since sockopen works by connecting to a server listening, if the files aren't web accessible, you can't use it to access them.

Comment: tip- anticipate that the long running script may crash, and have a plan to restart it/recover.

Answer (score 1):

You can use proc_open to run multiple processes without waiting for each process to finish.
You will have a process handle, you can terminate each process at any time and you can read the standard output of each process.

You can also communicate via pipes, which is optional.

Passing 1st param `php /your/path/to/script.php param1 "param2 x"` means starting a separate PHP process.

[proc_open (see Example #1)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

Ultimately you will want to use an infinite while loop + usleep (or sleep) to avoid maxing out on the CPU. Break when all processes finish, or after you killed them.

Edit: you can know if a process has exited prematurely.

Edit2: a simpler way of doing the above is [popen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php)

Comment: Can I also use exec() to run processes in parallel? If you run it in the background, that's parallel, right?

Comment: No, exec waits for the process to finish, and you have no control over it. You can run one process, but not many in parallel.

Comment: PHP.net says this:
"If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends."

So I should be able to run in parallel, right?

But will I be able to see when they all finish?

Comment: If such special output redirection is allowed (maybe on Linux). However this is a poor and cumbersome solution, while it is not needed (you have no handle of the process on which to check if the process is still runnning, you don't know when it finishes to check on the output, you can't kill it or find out it's PID). popen and proc_open are waaaay superior, and a perfect fit for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if I understand things correctly, the solution Tiberiu-Ionut Stan proposed implies that starting the processes with proc_open and waiting for them to finish will not be run as a cron script, but is part of a running program/service, right?

As far as I understand the cron jobs, the controller script user920050 was thinking of using would be started by cron on a schedule and each new instance would launch the processes all over again, do the waiting for them to finish and probably run in parallel with other cron-launched instances of the controller script.